# Can i use the Derby database in jelastic

Tags: java, deployment, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, jelastic

I discovered a new interesting gadget for deploying java apps on the web easier.
It is called [jelastic](http://www.jelastic.com), i want to deploy one of my apps, but i am not sure what to do if i want to use the derby database that is included in glassfish server. No idea where is the console in there.

Does someone know if is that possible?

Could someone point me to some tutorial on how to pack and deploy an app in glassfish V3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am from Jelastic support staff. We will provide opportunity of access for admin panel of GlassFish by cluster beginning from the next release (it will be launched next week). So you will not need to configure each instance. We'll try to analyze this question and write a tutorial on how to do this or something like this. Stay tuned!

Answer (score 1):

As I know, Jelastic provides few separate DB servers to pick: Maria, MySQL and Postgres.
Personally I like Postgres much better.

Answer (score 0):

Each separate glassfish instance would be running a separate Derby instance, and I doubt that is what you want. To run with Derby, you'd have to have separate Derby network server somewhere for your cloud servers to talk to.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you have 2 or more instances of GlassFish in environment, besides only 1 instance  (das node) will have derby inside, and derby database is still shutdown by default. Best solution in this case is using default [SQL databases](http://jelastic.com/docs/general-information) provided by Jelastic.